# Linux split file

Tags: linux, ksh

I have a file output.txt that contains:-

```
serverA  start of text
serverA  some more text
serverA  end of text
serverB  start of text
serverB  some more text
serverB  end of text
```

I would like to create 2 files from this named
serverA.html and serverB.html

Using KSH commands

Comment: What do you consider `ksh` commands?

Comment: any linux command that works in a Korn shell as the script I need to add this too is a .ksh script

Comment: please update the question with the (expected) contents of files `serverA.html` and `serverB.html`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your text is `servers.txt`:

```
awk '{print $0>$1".html"}' servers.txt
```